# JavaScript pattern providing optional callback interface but use promise inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, synchronous

I want to create a function, let's say a `readConfig` function.

```
readConfig(path [, callback(err, config)])
```

The callback here is optional. If there is no callback when called, the function will only use synchronous methods (`readFile(path)` and `configParser(string)` which return promises) to read the file and directly return the parsed config object. Exceptions are thrown directly. However when callback is provided, the function will use asynchronous methods and call the callback after finished. Exceptions are directly raised to callback but not thrown.

There are many similar codes to do sync and async work, so I want to use one method for both. How can a promise like function detect an async or sync call according to the caller's callback argument? And how can we ensure that the promise will act in synchronous way? Please show me a pattern for that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the promise acting in a synchronous way, but in JavaScript you can do `arguments.length` to get the number of arguments passed to a function.  If that equals 2 and `typeof arguments[1] === 'function'`, then you have a second argument that is a function.

As for personal taste, I'd recommend just having 2 different functions, one of them ending in `Sync`, à la http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html.  This module is replete with function pairs where one is async and the other isn't.

Also, remember that this is not async code:

```
function notAsync(cb) {
  cb(null)
}
```

That callback executes in the same tick.  You need to wrap it like so:

```
function async(cb) {
  process.nextTick(function(){ cb(null)})
}
```

or something like that.

Whatever you decide, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I'm using jQuery's deferred api. I wrap the callback in `.when` which allows you to attach a `.then()` to the callback, whether it is synchronous or asynchronous with a promise.

The solution should be to use your promise api's `when`. http://howtonode.org/promises

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/UwOLaVI/1/edit)**

```
$('#sync').click(function() {
  foo(function() {

  });
});
$('#async').click(function() {
  foo(function() {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function() {
      deferred.resolve();
    }, 500);

    return deferred.promise();
  });
});

function foo(callback) {
  $.when(callback()).then(function() {
    console.log('done!');
  });
}
```